# Connect ESP32 to a particular room in a nodejs server with socket.io

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, arduino, esp32

I am using arduino to programme my ESP32. This is the code I am using and it seems I am able to connect to the websocket server

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WebSocketClient.h>
 
const char* ssid     = "#######";
const char* password = "####";
 
char path[] = "/";
char host[] = "192.168.#.##";
 
WebSocketClient webSocketClient;
WiFiClient client;

void connnect(){
   if (client.connect(host, 5000)) {
    Serial.println("Connected");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Connection failed.");
  }
 
  webSocketClient.path = path;
  webSocketClient.host = host;
  if (webSocketClient.handshake(client)) {
    Serial.println("Handshake successful");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Handshake failed.");
  }
}
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
 
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
 
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
 
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
 
  delay(5000);
 
 connnect();
 
}
 
void loop() {
  String data;
 
  if (client.connected()) {
 
    webSocketClient.sendData("Info to be echoed back");
 
    webSocketClient.getData(data);
    if (data.length() > 0) {
      Serial.print("Received data: ");
      Serial.println(data);
    }
 
  } else {
    Serial.println("Client disconnected.");
    connnect();
  }
 
  delay(3000);
 
}
```

In the server side I have a nodejs express server with socket.io. What I want to do is to connect to a specific room with the ESP32. How can I connect to a room. What is the change I have to do in this code.

Thanks for the help

Comment: socket.io is not "compatible" to websockets. socket.io use websockets to communicate with the server but is not plain websockets. its a protocol on top of ws. You can switch on the server side to plain websockets.

Comment: Would you please recommend any starting tips to build a ESP32 websocket client and Nodejs websocket server

Comment: What it looks for me, you have a ws implementation for you esp (with `WebSocketClient.h`). I could post you a simple ws server in/with `node.js`

Comment: @Marc that would be really helpful if you can do that